# Error while creating a database in mongodb (not a valid database name in mongo.js)

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to create a database in mongo db using command `use db shorten`

when i run the mongod instance it outputs this
[image: Mongod instance]

but when try to run mongo in the separate terminal it gives error creating a database

[image]

the data/db permissions are set to 755 and i couldn't find anything related to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your db is called 'shorten' you should just type `use shorten`. It's the extra 'db' in there that's messing you up.